# REdisJSON Command JSON.SET is not working in syslog-ng destination

Tags: redis, syslog-ng, redisjson

I have tried "LPUSH" command in the following code, it works but redisjson command is not working

```
destination d_redis {
    redis(
        host("localhost")
        port(6379)
        command("JSON.SET", "test", "${MESSAGE}")
    );
};
```

Can someone help to find out the reason why it is not working and how to make it as work?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.SET needs 3 parameters.

```
JSON.SET <key> <path> <json>
```

https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonset